# LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-16.04, nokogiri

Trying to run rake assets precompile with production mode as follows.

```
rake assets:precompile
```

It is working fine for ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit) and 16.06(32 bit.) But getting Load Error on 16.04(64 bit) in aws ec2.

Here's my full stack trace:

```
rake aborted! LoadError: incompatible library version -
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in
`rescue in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/loofah-2.2.2/lib/loofah.rb:3:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.4/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:2:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:58:in
`<module:Helpers>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in
`<module:ActionView>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity/utility/view_helpers.rb:25:in
`<module:PublicActivity>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity/utility/view_helpers.rb:2:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity.rb:68:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/learnmusicco/config/application.rb:7:in `<top
(required)>' /home/ubuntu/learnmusicco/Rakefile:4:in `<top
(required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in
`<top (required)>'

Caused by: LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/2.3/nokogiri
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/lib/nokogiri.rb:30:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/loofah-2.2.2/lib/loofah.rb:3:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.4/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:2:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:58:in
`<module:Helpers>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in
`<module:ActionView>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity/utility/view_helpers.rb:25:in
`<module:PublicActivity>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity/utility/view_helpers.rb:2:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in
`load_dependency'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in
`require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/public_activity-1.5.0/lib/public_activity.rb:68:in
`<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/learnmusicco/config/application.rb:7:in `<top
(required)>' /home/ubuntu/learnmusicco/Rakefile:4:in `<top
(required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in
`<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Did you have libgmp-dev installed on the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try running `gem pristine --all` to automatically uninstall and reinstall all installed gems in the current environment. That might sort out your issue.

If that doesn't work, try running `` rm -rf `rvm gemdir`/bundler/gems `` to forcibly remove all of your gems and then try another `bundle install`.

Comment: I had to run `bundle pristine` but this answer definitely pointed me in the right direction. Many thanks!

Comment: +1 for `bundle pristine` in 2020 with an older 2.5.1 setup that kept throwing a `incompatible library version`. Tried uninstalling nokogiri and reinstalling but that didn't work where pristine did work.